# Table view combined fields, separate sort

Tags: views

I'm looking for some assistance in setting up a table view to be able to sort merged columns separately.  At a high level I have the following view table:

| First Name | Last Name | Age/Weight^ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ken | Davidson | Age: 42 Weight: 200 |

I have all three columns sortable, except that the third column only sorts by `Age`, even though it has two possible sort options.  Clicking the `Age/Weight` will only sort by Age, there is no way that I can see to make it sortable by either Age or Weight.

I found a couple links here that don't seem overly optimistic, but I'm hoping that things have changed:

- [How to sort View on rewritten field?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/298581/how-to-sort-view-on-rewritten-field) My fields are re-written to just add the internal label `<span>Age</span><span>{{ age__value }}</span>` I don't need to sort by the re-write.

**Edit**

The more I look into this, the more I'm starting to think that the only way to do this is by providing a custom template `views-view-table--custom-view-name.html.twig` and would need to overwrite the one section:

```
      <tr>
        {% for key, column in header %}
          {% if column.default_classes %}
            {%
              set column_classes = [
                'views-field',
                'views-field-' ~ fields[key],
              ]
            %}
          {% endif %}
          <th{{ column.attributes.addClass(column_classes).setAttribute('scope', 'col') }}>
            <div class="th-wrap">
              {%- if column.wrapper_element -%}
                <{{ column.wrapper_element }}>
                  {% if column.title == 'sort by Age/Weight' %}
                    <!-- Add two links hardcoding the URL appropriately -->
                  {% else %}
                    {%- if column.url -%}
                    <a href="{{ column.url }}" title="{{ column.title }}">{{ column.content }}{{ column.sort_indicator }}</a>
                  {%- else -%}
                    {{ column.content }}{{ column.sort_indicator }}
                  {%- endif -%}
                </{{ column.wrapper_element }}>                    
                  {% endif %}                  
              {%- else -%}
                {%- if column.url -%}
                  <a href="{{ column.url }}" title="{{ column.title }}">{{ column.content }}{{ column.sort_indicator }}</a>
                {%- else -%}
                  {{- column.content }}{{ column.sort_indicator }}
                {%- endif -%}
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          </th>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
```

Before I follow this path, does it seem like an optimal solution? The issue here is that I would lose the ability to display the sort indicator, since the column is still directly related to `Age/Weight` (which is just Age) instead of the individual columns.

Is there a global variable available in the `views-view-table` renderer that I would be able to check for the actual sort column?  Is the URL available for parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working - in the most Drupal best practice way I could think of.  If this is way off, I'd love some guidance on how to do this properly, but for those looking for the same:

I added a theme preprocessor to update the table `$variables` with the sort/order at the highest level:

```
function sc_preprocess_views_view_table(&$variables) {  
  $view = $variables['view'];
  $handler = $view->style_plugin;
  $variables['sorting'] = array(
    'active' => $handler->active, 
    'order' => $handler->order
  );
}
```

The twig file was updated with:

```
// views-view-table--custom-view--page.html.twig
{% if column.title == 'sort by Age/Weight' %}
  <a href="{{ sc_column_sort_url('field_hfs_age', sorting) }}" title="Sort by age">age</a>
  {% if sorting['active'] == 'field_hfs_age' %}
    {{ sc_column_sort_indicator(sorting['order']) }}
  {% endif %} /
  
  <a href="{{ sc_column_sort_url('field_hfs_weight', sorting) }}" title="Sort by weight">weight</a>
  {% if sorting['active'] == 'field_hfs_weight' %}
    {{ sc_column_sort_indicator(sorting['order']) }}
  {% endif %}
{% else %}
  // Original code
{% endif %}
```

And two custom Twig Functions were created

```
  /**
   * Provides common functionality for building the custom column sort URL required.
   * @param $name the name of the current field
   * @param $sorting the associated array of the current sort
   */
  public function scTableSortUrl($name, $sorting) {
    $nextSort = ($sorting['active'] == $name && $sorting['order'] == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    return "?order={$name}&sort={$nextSort}";
  }

  /**
   * Display the table sort indicator of the current custom table.   I'm sure this exists somehwere
   * else, but I can't find it.
   * @param $initial the initial sort order [asc | desc]
   */
  public function scTableSortIndicator($initial) {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'tablesort_indicator',
      '#style' => $initial,
    ];
  }
```

https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/drupal-9-creating-custom-twig-functions-and-filters  for reference.